# Correct ROR model callback for creation associated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have associated models `User` and `Channel` in Rails 3 app. `Channel` is created at the moment of `User` creation

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create do
    self.channels.build
  end
  has_many :channels  
end    

class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validations block
  ...
end
```

Problem is that if validations for Channel will not pass `User` will be created at DB but `Channel` won't. In what callback place `Channel` creation to create `User` and `Channel` in one 'transaction'? Or, maybe, there is another right way?

Thanks in advance.

**UPD1:**
`Channel` autocreate on `User` create placed in model because in some cases objects created not invoking controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think too much. This is very common case and has a convention.

Firstly at Pedro said, you need a validation of association in Channel model. This will prevent saving of channel without user_id.

Then, in controller's `create` action, you just make sure all params including user object is sent here for creation.

Comment: I didn't place association create code in controller but in model because in some circumstances controller isn't used, for example: call `User.create!` from another model.

Comment: @MaksimKachalin, I can't think about any use case you should put record manipulation logic in another a model instead of controller. If you do have, it's better you update that in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated question. In the question I asked for another way maybe more correct. Do you think logic has to be placed in controller?

Comment: @MaksimKachalin, I suggest you give up this idea. This is not convention. If you want to create channel in User, what Channel are you going to create? Where does the data come from? These are all jobs of controller.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "accepts_nested_attributes_for"

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :channels
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :channels
end

class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user
  validations block
end

Answer (score 1):

Use `validates :channels, associated: true`.

You should probably review your Channel validations because if it is not saving, you're doing something your app doesn't expect.

Comment: Of course validations for `Channel` fails because I'm testing this behaviour just right now. `validates :channels, associated: true` added to `User` model has no affect, running db:seed: 
    u = User.create()
    u.save
still creates `User` while not `Channel`.